# I am trying to test my node API using jest but it is not working.I am unable to fix it out what might be the reason behind this and how to fix this?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

This is my main app.js file where i have define the path.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const categoriesRouter = require("./routes/categoriesRouter");
const productRouter = require("./routes/productRouter");
const userRouter = require("./routes/userRouter");
const orderRouter = require("./routes/ordersRouter");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MERO-HARDWARE-PASAL", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB connected"));

app.use("/api", categoriesRouter);
app.use("/api", productRouter);
app.use("/api", userRouter);
app.use("/api", orderRouter);
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));

app.get("*", function (req, res) {
  res.status(500).send("Oops Something Went Wrong!!!");
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is my userRouter.js file to handle the request related to user.

```
router.post("/signup", signup);
router.post("/signin", signin);
router.get("/signout", signout);
```

and this is my user.test.js file to define the test case

```
const request = require("supertest");
const express = require("express");
const userRouter = require("../routes/userRouter");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json);
app.use("/api", userRouter);
require("./config");

describe("Testing of user route", () => {
  test("should be able to register", () => {
    return request(app)
      .post("/signup")
      .send({
        name: "testing",
        email: "testing@gmail.com",
        password: "testing@gmail.com",
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
      });
  });
});
```

This is the error i am getting. I am being unable to fix the issue.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ6o4.png)

Here is the error message

> ```
> test/user.test.js (7.704 s)
>   Testing of user route
>     × should be able to register (5011 ms)
>
>   ● Testing of user route › should be able to register
>
>     : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not
> ```
>
> invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:
>
> ```
>        9 | 
>       10 | describe("Testing of user route", () => {
>     > 11 |   test("should be able to register", () => {
>          |   ^
>       12 |     return request(app)
>       13 |       .post("/api/signup")
>       14 |       .send({
>
>       at new Spec (C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
>       at Suite.<anonymous> (test/user.test.js:11:3)
>       at Object.<anonymous> (test/user.test.js:10:1)
>
>   console.log
>     Disconnecting ...
>
>       at test/config.js:20:13
>
> A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper
> ```
>
> teardown. Try running with --runInBand --detectOpenHandles to find
> leaks.

Comment: Please, provide the error in text form, it doesn't need to be an image. The problem is specific to Mongoose. Requests to unopened db connection result in pending promises and timeouts. Since you didn't include app file, no connection was established.

Comment: @EstusFlask I have added the error message in text and I have added a db connection but i have not include that file here.

Comment: Then please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the error. It's not evident that there's db connection, and it's unknown what happens in tested route and whether there are other reasons for a timeout. From my experience, a timeout with Mongoose almost always means that there's no connection.